# Rotate an object to a line between 2 points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a line between two points (Vector3) **V1 - V2**

I add an object on this line but initially it is always horizontal as in the picture on the left

It is a mesh object - **IMPORTANT**

How do I rotate this object to be along this line as in the picture on the right?

IMPORTANT to rotate every point in this mesh (not an object)

For further work, I need the exact locations of all the vertices

I try something like this but it's not the way to go:

```
Vector3 v = V2 - V1;
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(v, new Vector3(1, 1, 0));
rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);


// I rotate all the points in the mesh
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
{
     vertices[i] = RotatePointAroundAxis(vertices[i], pos, Vector3.up, rotation.eulerAngles.y);
}

public Vector3 RotatePointAroundAxis(Vector3 pointToRotate, Vector3 centerAxis, Vector3 axis, float angle)
{
     Vector3 point = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, axis) * (pointToRotate - centerAxis);
     Vector3 result = centerAxis + point;
     return result;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: LookRotation is the correct API for this but i'm not sure what the meaning of your second parameter is.  Typically this should be Vector3.up

Comment: @JoshBothun `Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(v, Vector3.up);` It works too, but the problem is different. If I draw a line from V1 to V2 that's okay, but otherwise, it doesn't rotate the object anymore. It is not universal

Comment: @JoshBothun Depending on the direction i should be changing it `rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0);`. Once `90` and then `-90` and then it would be ok but how to do it well so that it always works?

Answer (score 1):

It is way easier simply using

```
Vector3 v = V2 - V1;
yourObject.transform.right = v;
```

or if you want to go for one of the other axes

```
yourObject.transform.forward = v;
```

or accordingly

```
yourObject.transform.up = v;
```

depending on your use case and desired result

---

After your Update I see you want/need it rather on mesh basis.

Here I would use a Matrix like e.g.

```
var deltaRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.right, v);
var matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, deltaRotation, Vector3.one);

var verts = mesh.verts;
for(var i = 0; i< verts.Length; i++)
{
    verts[i] = matrix.MultiplyPoint3x4(verts[i]);
}
mesh.verts = verts;
```

again if needed change the `Vector3.right` to `Vector3.forward` or `Vector3.up` etc accordingly.

Comment: I added some code as I rotate each point. The problem is getting the angle from `rotation.eulerAngles.y`. It may have a different sign, and this does not always work

Comment: @DeveloperApps you don't want to use `eulerAngles` at all ... I recommend reading the [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) ;) .. updated for a possible mesh solution using a matrix